# Quarkus - @Inject Logger causes NPE in test while using Mockito extension; @QuarkusTest works fine

Tags: java, logging, cdi, quarkus

`org.jboss.logging.Logger` with `@Inject` annotation in my code causes `NullPointerException` in my unit test annotated with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`, if I define it as a `org.mockito.@Mock`. It's fine if it's used in `@QuarkusTest` as `@Inject Logger`, as Quarkus will inject it.

I don't want to change my unit test to `@QuarkusTest` only for this reason. How can I avoid this NPE caused by logger not initialized by Mockito?

Is this question related? [Mock Quarkus provided logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633839/mock-quarkus-provided-logger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a workaround now:

- set logger in src to be package visibility, so it can be accessed from test
- org.mockito.@Mock it in JUnit test
- in @BeforeEach, set the mock to the class to test, like `someInstance.logger = mockLogger;`

It has no impact on the original code base, as Quarkus always requires the injected field to be package-private.